# TypeScript: variable type for "dynamic value" assigning?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can catch error from the following script.

```
let num: number = 1;
num = 'abc';
```

But the following script can be executed without error:

```
let num: number = 1;
let s = '{"a":"abc"}';
let j = JSON.parse(s);
num = j.a; // assigning a string "abc"
```

So what's the correct way to catch error from the second script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript applies type rules at compile time, not runtime. TypeScript does not have access to runtime values (it doesn't even exist at runtime; it gets compiled down to JavaScript). If you want to validate data (such as JSON), you need a runtime validator, not types. For example, see [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your JSON using an interface because the return value of `JSON.parse` is of type [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any).

```js
interface JSON {
    /**
      * Converts a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string into an object.
      * @param text A valid JSON string.
      * @param reviver A function that transforms the results. This function is called for each member of the object.
      * If a member contains nested objects, the nested objects are transformed before the parent object is.
      */
    parse(text: string, reviver?: (this: any, key: string, value: any) => any): any;
}
```

```js
let num: number = 1;
let s = '{"a":"abc"}';
let _j = JSON.parse(s);
interface MyJSON {
  [key: string]: number
}
let j = _j as MyJSON
num = j.a;
```

Comment: But my purpose is to accept correct data. String `s` is gotten from API. I want it be assigned if data type is correct, and catch error if data type wrong. In your answer even I set `s` to `{"a":123}` still thrown error.

Comment: @Elect2 Please see updated answer with correct type `number`. For more elaborate JSON objects, you have to add all properties to the interface.

Comment: After running updated script,  `num` was assigned `abc` without error.